# sql one-to-one join / match

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

hello I need solution for this kind of problem:

sample:
tblPeople:

```
 - id   Value  carColor
 1. Pid1  boy1  blue
 2. Pid2  boy2  blue
 3. Pid3  boy3  blue
 4. Pid4  girl1 red
 5. Pid5  girl2 red
```

tblCars:

```
 - id   Value
 1. Cid1  blue
 2. Cid2  blue
 3. Cid3  red
 4. Cid4  red
 5. Cid5  red
```

condition:
 - boys can use only blue cars but girls - red only 
 - people can use 1 car only, car fits 1 person only

distribute cars between people

expected result(s):

```
 1. Pid1  boy1 Cid1 blue
 2. Pid2  boy2 Cid2 blue
 3. Pid3  boy3 (no enough blue car - skipping)
 4. Pid4  girl1 Cid3 red
 5. Pid5  girl2 Cid4 red
```

or

```
 1. Pid1  boy1 Cid2 blue
 2. Pid2  boy2 Cid1 blue
 3. Pid3  boy3 (no enough blue car - skipping)
 4. Pid4  girl1 Cid5 red
 5. Pid5  girl2 Cid3 red
```

for now I'm using select top 1 on join in cycle with marking chosen records to remove it in next matching, but it takes lot of time ...

can anyone help with it?
thanks

Comment: A simple row_number partitioned by gender(I assume you have a column for that) and a row_number partitioned by color would make this quite simple.

Comment: yes, I have the column, tblPeople - updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by enumerating the cars and enumerating the people, and then doing a `join`:

```
select p.*, c.*
from (select p.*,
             row_number() over (partition by gender order by gender) as seqnum
      from tblPeople p
     ) p left join
     (select c.*,
             row_number() over (partition by color order by color) as seqnum
      from cars c
     ) c
     on p.seqnum = c.seqnum and
        ( (p.gender = 'boy' and c.color = 'blue') or
          (p.gender = 'girl' and c.color = 'red')
        ) ;
```

This should be much, much faster than your current method.

Note:  You can use `newid()` for ordering if you want to randomize the assignment each time you run the query.

Comment: I mention this as a comment and lightning fast Gordon typed out the solution. :)

Comment: sorry for my misunderstanding, but I can't see linking by condition where boys on blue cars and girls on red ..... explain that, please

and yes, I have carColor field with color value in tblPeople (updating now)

Comment: @OleksiyKustlyvy . . . Ooops, that condition is also important.